# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los datos de mi arreglo y convertirlos al formato de fecha y hora?

Tags: javascript, html, css, momentjs

estoy trabajando en un proyecto de angular donde tengo el crud basico y al ingresar datos al la base de datos tengo input de tipo **date** donde los datos se almacenan de esta forma 2022-04-30 uso la libreria **moment()** para convertir los datos ingresados al tipo fecha
pero quiero que los datos se muestren en la vista como la fecha normal asi de esta forma,
si en la base de datos tengo 2022-04-30 en la vista quiero ver esto 30/04/2022, la idea es poder acceder a los datos que recibo y pasarlos con **moment()** a la vista que necesito
uso material angular asi que la tabla viene de este.

**HTML**

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="fecha" class="columnas">
<th  *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha</th>
<td *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.diacita}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="Hora" class="columnas">
<th *matHeaderCellDef>Hora</th>
<td *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.horacita}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

en **{{element.diacita}}** practicamente muestra esto 2022-04-30 y en **{{element.horacita}}** esto 16:00 con **moment()** estoy consiente que puedo usarlo para que me diga el formato de fecha que deseo pero como accedo a los datos que viene de la bd
**TS**

```js
  fecha: string = moment().format(/*2022-04-30*/);
  hora: string = moment().format(/*16:00*/)

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['fecha', 'Hora'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Persona>([]);

  constructor(private personaService: PersonasService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { 
    this.getPersonas()
  }

  getPersonas(){
    this.personaService.getPersonas().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.dataSource.data = res;
        console.log(this.dataSource.data);
        /*dataSource recibe objetos por parte de res*/
        
        
      },
      err => console.error(err)
    )
  }
```

tengo solo como 2 meses de experiencia con angular y pues creo que debe haber una forma de hacer esto y otra cosa no puedo ingresar los datos a la db con el formato normal (dd-mm-yyyy) pues al tener que actualizarlos los input del formulario de actualizar no se auto completaran.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voy a dejar esta respuesta por si alguien tiene este inconveniente,
Primero lo que debes hacer es dejar tus variables globales vacías

```
fecha: string;
hora: string;
```

luego para acceder a tu arreglo donde traes tus datos accedes a el de esta forma

```
getPersonas(){
this.personaService.getPersonas().subscribe(
  res => {
    res.push(object => {
        this.fecha = moment().format(object.diacita);
        this.hora = moment().format(object.horacita);
    })       

    this.dataSource.data = res;
    console.log(this.dataSource.data);
    
  },
  err => console.error(err)
)
}
```

y en el HTML hacer esto

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="fecha" class="columnas">
<th  *matHeaderCellDef>Fecha</th>
<td *matCellDef="let element"> {{fecha}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="Hora" class="columnas">
<th *matHeaderCellDef>Hora</th>
<td *matCellDef="let element"> {{hora}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

esa es la idea básica, espero les sirva.